# How to print the value of a variable next to a string, which the value of variable is an integer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Hello Python coders how are you doing today? I have a question...

How to print the value of a variable next to a string, which the value of variable is an integer?

I know a way to print variables in Python 3:

```
print(variable)
```

Another way I have seen is:

```
print("Some string here: ", variable)
```

I tried it on my code and somehow it works, but not as I want... I mean the line of code that I wanna print out is:

```
print("Dogs Years: ", human_years)
```

and the output of this line is:

```
('Dogs Years: ', 19.5)
```

But the expected output is:

```
Dogs Years: 19.5
```

How to achieve that??

EDIT: I have finally fixed this issue. The main problem was that I included the double quotes instead of the single one.

it should be like this: `print(f'Dogs Years: {human_years}')` where `human_years` is actually the variable.

Comment: You're using Python 2, not Python 3.  To get what you want, either switch to Python 3, or else remove the parentheses from `print` in Python 2.

Comment: Try print `('Dogs Years: ' +str(human_years))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [f' prefix](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/):

`print(f'Dogs Years: {human_years}')`

Comment: Hey Hello There :) Thanks for taking time to answer my question. Well, I tried this with format but it was leading to a syntax error since I was using python 3 I guess. In fact I already found the solution. I putted %d(inside of double quotes) and %(outside of double quotes) and it solved my problem. Best Regards :D

Answer (score 0):

```py
print('Dog years: {}'.format(human_years))
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post.  Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Comment: Hey Hello There :) Thanks for taking time to answer my question. Well, I tried this with format but it was leading to a syntax error. In fact I already found the solution. I putted %d(inside of double quotes) and %(outside of double quotes). Basically it solved my problem. Best Regards :D